# Displaying binary code of a file in ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, file, binary

I want to display the binary code of a music file. But somehow the code below doesn't seem to work. Any suggestions??

```
function binary() {
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {  // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else {  // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","1.wav",true);
    xmlhttp.overrideMimeType("text/plain; charset=x-user-defined");
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(buffer) {
        var binaryCode = "";
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
            var binStr = this.responseText;
            for (var i=0; i<binStr.length; i++) {
                var byte = binStr.charCodeAt(i) & 0xff;  // get byte at i
                binaryCode += byte;
            }   
        }
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = binaryCode; // should display binary code
    };
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not all byte values are expressible in a string and will not appear or cause the string to cut off short.

XMLHttpResponse.ResponseText/ResponseXML will return the http response content as a string. Any byte values of 0 for example will terminate the string.

Have the server return a Base64 representation of the bytes and decode into byte values on the client side.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be working fine on my chrome browser.
What is exactly the problem your are experimenting ?

You may want to display the binary in an hexadecimal form by doing something like:

```
binaryCode += '0x' + byte.toString(16) + ' '
```

edit:
this jsfiddle works on my chrome:
http://jsfiddle.net/e6Kfk/

However, i do not think that this method is crossbrowser, especially if you want to deal with ie (haven't tested it though)

Comment: On my chrome browser it doesn't seem to work. Nothing is displayed. I don't know whether the problem is the music file.

Comment: well hard to say from my point of view, but the first thing to check is if it actually gets into the if (..status == 200) and if the data length is correct.. use chrome debugger and console.log to help you